# How to encrypt an entire portable HDD, so that it cannot be read/written without the password for it?

Tags: tools, disk-encryption, file-encryption

I use a portable USB drive (Seagate FreeAgent Go Flex) to keep all my personal stuff, and though the HDD company does offer a password scheme to control access to it, that would work only on windows, as one could easily mount it in Linux and bypass it.

I'm looking for a solution that would *encrypt the entire drive*, making it impossible to read/write anything without knowing the password. Does anyone know of any security tools (open-source would be the best !!) that would enforce this regardless of the OS being used to mount the HDD ? If not, what alternatives would you suggest to safeguard the data ?

Comment: I recommend [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/), the successor to TrueCrypt.

Comment: Note that in most cases, it is possible to overwrite the entire disk even if it is encrypted - the only exception is an ATA password on the actual drive controller. Which you might not be able to do over USB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit** TrueCrypt is now defunct. So this answer requires work...

[TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.org) is what you're looking for.

Other (paid) solutions include PGP Desktop, and Jetico BestCrypt.

Comment: Don't forget that for Truecrypt to work you need to have admin rights at the system you will use the disk.

Comment: Truecrypt is great. It's free, opensource, and works on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X

Comment: Truecrypt meets every one of your requirements.  Don't forget to DONATE!  :)